# Hide part of a page for bots using captcha and limit the number of times to offer captcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I want to hide part of a page (a div) for bots (such as Google Bot), but it should be visible to Humans.
I did quite a bit of research on the above topic but could not find a proper solution. Using the knowledge obtain from searching I came up with the following work around.

1. Users are offerd to solve a Google-reCaptcha
2. User solve the captcha and submit a request to view content
3. A Persistant-Cookie and a new Session-Variable is created
4. Above details are recorded in a database with IP and User-Agent
5. As long as Session is valid user can view the content
6. If Session is absent, but a valid cookie is present
7. Create a new Session-Variable and update records in the database
8. If cookie or session invalid
9. Offer reCaptcha again

So the users do not have to solve a Captcha on each visit to the site and a valid cookie can be used in different pages for the same purpose.

Any comments on how to limit the number of times a user has to solve a Captcha or any weakness of the propose method will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Showing different content to the Google Bot than you show to humans (i.e., cloaking) will result in your entire site being completely deindexed by Google, as it violates their Webmaster Guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355

Comment: @JosephSible thanks for the info, what if I am trying to hide only a small piece of information such as a phone number or an email address?

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest you reversing the approach by making an input text box then use css to make it invisible to the human eye then during validation you check if this invincible text box has been filled ? If it has then you end validation as only a bot could have seen it, this is called **Honeypot Validation**.

Never depend on data from cookies all user inputs are dangerous and can be manipulated, so step 6 is wrong.

About IP address it is against the law in some countries to store IP addresses of your visitors with out their consent, make sure your users know that their IP addresses will be stored, should they decide to view and continue to use the site.

Comment: I was thinking almost all the websites that contain analytic functions and user authentication systems store user IP address

Comment: Yes some of them do, most of them encrypt these IP addresses before storing them to protect the users while the rest let you know they will be collecting data on you in their terms and conditions page or legality sections

Comment: I read more about HoneyPots, I am wondering if they can be used in a project which expects a decent level of reliability?

Comment: Depends on what type of **Honeypot** you're using but you can not solely depend on it as your only check point.

Comment: Some validation deals with speed from the time the page loaded completely to the time the form was submitted if its too quick that user is flagged as a bot. Like i said there are many types and the question is now of topic of the original question.